# Excecute a method only once for suite of suites testng xml file

Tags: java, testng

Is there a way to run a method(like @AfterSuite) after all suites in a testng suite file are completed ?

For example, consider this testng xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" preserve-order="true" thread-count="5">
<suite name="TestNG example suite"  > 
<!-- suite name="Suite Name" --> 
        <suite-files>
               <suite-file path="./suiteA.xml" />
               <suite-file path="./suiteB.xml" />
               <suite-file path="./suiteC.xml" />
        </suite-files>
</suite>
```

I want to perform some operation(like downloading logs) only after suiteC.xml is completed, i.e. after all suites are completed.

Comment: How about implementing your own [`ISuiteListener`](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-listeners) and add your custom login in the `onFinish()` method ([some more samples](https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/testng-listeners/))?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. onFinish() is called after every suite. What I want is to call a method before the parent suite starts and another method after the parent suite completes. The suite file can be a suite of suites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to implement your own IExecutionListener.

IExecutionListener has two methods, onExecutionStart() and onExecutionFinish(). Method onExecutionStart() is invoked before TestNG starts running the suites and onExecutionFinish() is run once all the suites have been run.

Reference:

https://www.javarticles.com/2015/04/testng-iexecutionlistener-example.html